# Does Xcode take care of multiple .git in sub-folders nicely?

Tags: xcode, git

For a new project `Foobar` in the `~/Code` folder, Xcode creates the following in `~/Code/Foobar/`:

- `.git`
- `Foobar`
- `Foobar.xcodeproj`

For third party libraries, I put them in a `~/Code/Foobar/Vendor` folder, for example:

```
 cd ~/Code/Foobar/Vendor
 git clone https://github.com/ohho/GPUImage.git
```

There two `.git` folders:

- `~/Code/Foobar/.git/`
- `~/Code/Foobar/Vendor/GPUImage/.git/`

In the future, will Xcode's `Source Control` > `Commit Selected Files...` feature work nicely with both `.git` repositories?

Comment: You probably want to look at Submodules: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules or Subtree Merging: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Subtree-Merging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XCode 4 does know how to manage submodules, if you chose that approach (see "[Xcode 4 workspace with two interdependent projects: should I also use git submodule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8787956/xcode-4-workspace-with-two-interdependent-projects-should-i-also-use-git-submod)").
Such an approach is illustrated in "[adding a simple library to an xcode 4 project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6976502/6309)".

But even without submodule, it should manage nested git repos just fine. The parent git repo would ignore the nested one.